# TableView glitches when loading an HTML content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, html-parsing

**I am rendering my HTML string on the label.
Also i have rendered it on the UIView and the WebView Still the tableview glitches**

I applied this function which renders the html on the label.
here's the code.

```
func getAttributedString(HTMLString: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let data = Data(HTMLString.utf8)
    let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
    return attributedString!
}
```

And using it on the cellForRowAt as follows

```
 discussionListCell.discriptionLabel.attributedText = self.getAttributedString(HTMLString: discussionResponse[indexPath.row].postMsg ?? "")
```

Hers the sample of the HTML string i m receiving with image.
"he
img src=\"http:\\45.35.4.250\DevImageUpload\60ac0c0f-7751-4088-9a01-466a51a8a5b7.png\">"

Thanks in the advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dispatch to update UILabel

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.discussionListCell.discriptionLabel.attributedText = self.getAttributedString(HTMLString: discussionResponse[indexPath.row].postMsg ?? "")
  }
```

Try reloading your tableView like below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
```

Comment: Tried you solution but now i m facing weird issue of data miss-place  in the table view cell.
now sometimes it shows similar data in multiple cells.

Comment: Above solution works fine, you might have not handle tableview correctly. Please share more code. I have updated my answer above. Please check!

Comment: I have created the object of the cell and only thing which i m doing is parsing html to that single label and returning the cell 
Here's the code
 
`let discussionListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiscussionListCountyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DiscussionListCountyTableViewCell

 DispatchQueue.main.async {
            discussionListCell.discriptionLabel.attributedText = self.getAttributedString(HTMLString: self.discussionResponse[indexPath.row].postMsg ?? "")
        }
return discussionListCell`

Comment: Yes I have Also reloaded the tableView same

Comment: I tried the above solution, but still there is a glitch.